# Install GApps without flash it

Tags: google-apps

I know we can download it in a zip format in order to flash in recovery mode, for exemple from opengapps project. 
What are others solution to install GApps on any android device without to flash? 
Edit : without root and without flash

GApps : Google applications + Google play services and framework

Comment: What else are you expecting instead of flashing?

Comment: If you want to install without modifying `/system` then it's impossible. But if you simply wany to DIY without using a custom recovery, it's OK.

Comment: @esQmo : In others words, how to have GApps when recovery is missing and the device is not rooted.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to install without modifying `/system` then it's impossible. **So the answer is "No, you can't" with neither root access nor recovery flashing.** But if you simply wany to DIY without using a custom recovery, it's OK.
Takine [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org) as example. Download their ZIP and extract it.

1. Install BusyBox
2. Use `busybox lunzip` to extract the `.tar.lz` files in `Core/`
3. Move files other than APKs to `/system`. You will find things to be merges into `etc/` and `framework/`. Take care of file mode (permissions) and owner/group.
4. Install `GoogleServicesFramework.apk` **as system app**. In my experiments it sometimes fail if not installed as system app.
5. Install the rest of the APKs as normal.

You can't install GApps without modifying `/system`. As you see, there are quite a few configuration files that will be merged into `/system/etc` during installation, and a few *essential* framework JARs to be installed to `'/system/framework`. They won't work if installed elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to be a solution with root access. I edited my question to add without root.

Answer (score -1):

Google for play services framework and play store APKs (hosted third party) (I believe running the play store will install/update the framework, so that might be the only one you need), then install the rest of them from the play store. If you're rooted, titanium backup can try to convert some of them to system apps.