# installing gapps without custom recovery

Tags: google-play-store

i have a SM-J7008 which was recently flashed but has no google apps installed. i read it was possible to in stall them using busybox. i would like a little more detail with the method mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173747/150986):

> If you want to install without modifying /system then it's impossible.
>   So the answer is "No, you can't" with neither root access nor recovery
>   flashing. But if you simply wany to DIY without using a custom
>   recovery, it's OK. Takine OpenGApps as example. Download their ZIP and
>   extract it.
>
> ```
> Install BusyBox
> Use busybox lunzip to extract the .tar.lz files in Core/
> Move files other than APKs to /system. You will find things to be merges into etc/ and framework/. Take care of file mode (permissions)
> ```
>
> and owner/group.
>       Install GoogleServicesFramework.apk as system app. In my experiments it sometimes fail if not installed as system app.
>       Install the rest of the APKs as normal.
>
> You can't install GApps without modifying /system. As you see, there
>   are quite a few configuration files that will be merged into
>   /system/etc during installation, and a few essential framework JARs to
>   be installed to '/system/framework. They won't work if installed
>   elsewhere.

Comment: Are you answering the question you asked yourself? If yes, crop the answer part out and put it in a proper answer; else, make it clear what the whole latter part is for (maybe it belongs in a blockquote?).

Comment: i am knew to this.i copied a response which i believe can help me but i need a little more detail on how exactly to go about it

Comment: I put it in a blockquote for you. To me the instruction seems quite clear: if you are rooted or has a custom recovery, you could proceed to just flash the GAPPS zip; if not, just don't think about it. As for `busybox`, it's just how the zip itself handles the installation, it's not what we as end users should care about. Just go get root or custom recovery figured out.

Comment: That text looks very familiar to me. I think it's **my** answer :)

Comment: i am rooted but a custom recovery is not available for my model SM-J7008

Comment: yes it is yours, can you explain the steps any more clear

Comment: Does anyone think it's a good practice to post detailed answer here?

Comment: i do not know but anything you can do i can get it installed wil be great

Comment: @iBug Didn't know he just copied it here... Added a link pointing to your original. Still, I reckon the text better be kept here for clarity.

Comment: Probably you can take the discussion to the chat room, if the instruction gets too long and requires step-by-step guidance...

Comment: if that is possible then yeah. my phone is rooted,busybox installed and the Gapps on my sdcard. i just need to know what to extract from where to where

Comment: Why not try extracting some of them and figure out the directory tree by yourself? It's very simple.

Comment: i have never used busybox before so can you tell me at least how to use it to unzip the tar.lz files